# nested partial views with viewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, viewmodel

**edit - just rewording the question**

If I have countries>states>cities

In my country controller, I fill a viewmodel with the country useing id, along with its states.

In the view, I can then say "for each state, show population".

What i don't understand, is how to also say, in the same view, "for each state, show each city".

Is everything in the same view model? Am I supposed to use nested partial views? How do I pass models from country view to state partial view to city partial view?

**end edit**

I have data organized in a parent>child>child>child fashion

Here are my viewmodel entities

```
public country country { get; set; }
public IList<state> states { get; set; }
public IList<city> cities { get; set; }
```

Here is my view

```
@model myproject.viewModel.vwcountry
@for (var c = 0; c < Model.country.states.Count(); c++)
{
     @Html.Partial("_states", Model.states[c]);
}
```

And the first partial view model

```
@model myModel.state
//partial view displays stuff from model
```

This all was working fine.

Now, I want to add the children of state. This is where I'm lost.

I feel that I should be passing the view model instead of the state model, but that won't even compile.

I feel there should be a seperate view model like this...

```
public state state { get; set; }
public IList<cities> cities { get; set; }
```

But this view model can't be made available to the view becuase in the current context, it doesn't exist.

I imagine this is a common pattern, but I haven't found a similar example...

Comment: What's stopping you creating the view models exactly how you need them?

Comment: I can, however, if the first partial view is strongly typed for the root entity (not the viewmodel), it won't be able to pass on the viewmodel to the next child. If its strongly typed for the viewmodel, the call from the parent will be passing the wrong model type (it will be passing the root entity type when the partial view expects a viewmodel). Visual Studio won't let me pass a viewmodel here:
@Html.Partial("_bookingleadroomflows", "CANT PASS A VIEWMODEL");

FURTHER, there are multiple children here, so I have to pass like this (next comment)

Comment: for (var r = 0; r < Model.items.Count(); r++)
{@Html.Partial("_mypartial", Model.item[r]);                              }

Comment: It would like to pass @Html.Partial("_mypartial", ViewModel.iteminviewmodel[r]); but something like this will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

your model is not correct. here is the correct model:

```
public class vwcountry
{
public country country { get; set; }
public IList<state> states { get; set; }
}

public class state
{
public state state { get; set; }
public IList<city> cities { get; set; }
}
```